# Encoding that works for German letters in QField

Tags: qgis, csv, qfield, encoding

In my project I work with the German letters `ü`, `ö`, `ß`, `ä`, etc.
I joined my shapefile with tables (Excel, CSV).
For showing the German letters above I need an encoding that displays these. I chose `ISO-8859-15` or `ISO-8859-1` as with the standard `UTF-8` these are not shown correctly.
In my QGIS project everything works fine. But when import in QField the encoding does not work anymore.

I know UTF-8 is standard for QField, but has anyone an idea how I can work with the German letters?

Any other encoding works in QField for German letters?

Or is there anything that makes German letters works in UTF-8 in CSV in QGIS?

Comment: Have you solved you problem or not yet? If you have found working solution, please, describe it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a lot of wild trying I solved the problem.
If the csv are added with the browser instead with "Add Layer...", it works in QField.
In result in the properties of the tables it is a different path and memory. As the memory "Delimited text file" it does not work. Only with "CSV". Then the encoding is irrelevant.